# Sublime text 3 изменить текст с помощью регулярных выражений

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, sublime-text

В `sublime text 3` нужно использовать регулярное выражение и заменить текст так, чтобы из текста:

```
привет\Приветос! как тебя зовут?
привет\Привет привет
привет\Салют!
как дела\Да как посмотреть.
как дела\Всё в порядке. А у тебя как дела?
как дела\Как в сказке!!!
```

Получить это:

```
--привет
-Приветос! как тебя зовут?
--привет
-Привет привет
--привет
-Салют!
--как дела
-Да как посмотреть.
--как дела
-Всё в порядке. А у тебя как дела?
--как дела
-Как в сказке!!!
```

Или же решение с помощью `python`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Код:***

```py
import re


with open('text.txt') as f:
    string = f.read()

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    res = re.sub(r'\\', '\n-', '--' + re.sub(r'\n', '\n--', string))
    f.write(res)
```

***text.txt:***

```html
привет\Приветос! как тебя зовут?
привет\Привет привет
привет\Салют!
как дела\Да как посмотреть.
как дела\Всё в порядке. А у тебя как дела?
как дела\Как в сказке!!!
```

***output.txt:***

```html
--привет
-Приветос! как тебя зовут?
--привет
-Привет привет
--привет
-Салют!
--как дела
-Да как посмотреть.
--как дела
-Всё в порядке. А у тебя как дела?
--как дела
-Как в сказке!!!
```

Comment: Данный текст находится в файле text.txt. Можете пожалуйста заново указать код, чтобы текст читался с файла